# Add column to dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, nan

I would like to copy the contents of 'col_B' into a new column only when 'col_A' contents is numeric and not NaN. I appreciate that this may seem rudimentary but i'm very new to python. Thanks in advance

```
  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D

0      NaN    2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      NaN    1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      e      c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(~df['col_A'].isna(), df['col_B'], '')
print(df)

   col_A  col_B col_C col_D new_col
0    NaN      2     a     b
1    2.0      4     b     d       4
2    NaN      1     c     a
3    4.0      2     d     b       2
4    5.0      3     e     c       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Unfortunately this code produces a completely blank column for me.

Comment: Is your NaN really np.nan? Can you replace your NaN with np.nan and then try again?

Comment: I have now just replaced 'isna()' with 'notnull()' and strangely enough it copies the entire contents of col_A which is also not what I was after.

Comment: isna() should work here, works perfectly for me. Not sure why it isn't working for you. Something with your data.

Comment: How can I do this?   "....replace NaN with np.nan "

Comment: I changed the code as follows:  df['new_col'] = np.nan(df['col_A'].isna(), df['col_B'], '') and got this response TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: Also I only just noticed that your code had '~' included. I have added and now all is working!! Helps when I have my glasses on.